# CakePHP: reusing models, controllers, configuration but not views and routes

Tags: php, cakephp, code-reuse

Our website is going to work as follows:

- There's a central site www.example.org where everybody can register, change information, manage their 'business card'.
- Also, everybody will have companyname.example.org. Here users can publish a simple site based on information they change in the main site.

This site is being built on CakePHP. I'm wondering what a good setup for this is. After doing some googling it appears to be common to create a separate directory for controllers and models for reusing, but in this case I want to really share all the code, except routes and views.

Is it possible to change routes based on a domainname. Would this be considered 'appropriate' for CakePHP at all. Rather than a solution that 'does' the job, I would prefer to find the best practice.

Thanks!

Comment: Will you dynamically generate and write `.ctp` files for every new user or could it be purely database+template based?

Comment: Then I'm not quite sure where the problem is. :-) As far as I understand it's all within the same application then, isn't it? The only problem would be how to pipe requests for `company.example.com` through your Cake app at `example.com`, which should be accomplishable with a properly configured server and maybe some .htaccess magic. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: I found the solution (below). I'll accept after a few days if no better answers come in, but I'm assuming this is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using [this tutorial](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/hosting-admin-urls-on-a-subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, the routing engine in CakePHP has no concept of domains so what you could theoretically do is map a route eg /company1/post/1 to company1.example.com/post/1 using Apache rewrite

[Prefixing in routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/544/Prefix-Routing) is possible as I've used it before to produce a multilingual site eg /en/blog, /es/blog etc so it would be just a case of prefixing the company name in the route.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are `themes`.

CakePHP 1.3 has a [neat implementation](http://code.cakephp.org/wiki/1.3/new-features/plugin-assets) of that, but 1.2 works almost as good.

In your AppController, you will want to add something along those lines to load a different theme based on the host:

```
$mapThemes = array('company.example.com' => 'theme-1', 'store.example.com' => 'theme-shopping');
$this->theme = $mapThemes[env('SERVER_NAME')];
```

Of course, possibilities are endless. You can load `$mapThemes` from the database by letting every user define multiple themes, etc. But that's the general idea and what I believe is the Cake way of doing things.